# sizeof((int)(float)(char)i)) when int is defined (int)(float)(char) i;

Tags: c, sizeof

```
#include<stdio.h>
double i;

int main()
{
    (int)(float)(char) i;
    printf("%d", sizeof((int)(float)(char)i));
    return 0;
}
```

The above outputs 4 on a Micrsoft compiler. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof` is the size, in bytes, of the variable. In this case, `i` is being cast to an `int` which is 4 bytes.

These are the sizes of types on MS C++: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc953fe1(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: To be exact: `i` gets cast to a `char`, then to a `float` and finally to an `int` whose size is then used in sizeof. At least as long as the compiler doesn't do some optimization magic, the casts to `char` and `float` are absolutely not needed.

Comment: Yup - I should have said 'last cast'. I'd optimised my answer to ignore the unnecessary casts :)

Answer (score 2):

The last cast operation is to int, so u will get the sizeOf(int). Integer size differes form compiler to another, some return 2-bytes and onther return 4-bytes.

Comment: in 16bit compiler will be 2 and in 32 bit will 4bytes rite ?

Comment: I haven't seen a 2-byte `int` in some decades. You generally see a value of either `4` or `8` for `int` on commodity hardware nowadays.

Comment: @mr_eclair: Generally, though a compiler is free to have whatever integer sizes it wants, as long as it fits the following rule: sizeof(char) == 1 && sizeof(char) <= sizeof(short) && sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) && sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) && sizeof(char)*CHAR_BIT >= 8 && sizeof(short)*CHAR_BIT >= 16 && sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT >= 16 && sizeof(long)*CHAR_BIT >= 32

Comment: My c compiler (devcpp-4.9.9.2) return int as 2-byte.

Comment: @Alaa: DevC++ is an IDE, not a compiler. It's probably got MinGW behind the scenes. In fact, DevC++ is so old and unsupported that 4.9.9.2 uses MinGW GCC 3.4.2. I'm still quite surprised that it should have 16-bit `int`s, as 3.4.2 is only half a decade old or so.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal, u r right, it's an IDE but it has built-in compiler, and don't be surprised that when I first start learning C, I use an IDE with "blue background and yellow cursor", I dont' remeber it's name but it also return int as 2 byte.

Comment: @Alaa: Nope, the compiler is not built-in. It is simply shipped with the IDE application and the IDE is set, by default, to invoke it. Again, IDEs don't give datatypes as anything!

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` something tells you how many bytes it takes up in memory. Your platform and toolchain clearly has 32-bit integers; it's telling you that `int`, on your toolchain (compiler), takes up 4 bytes.